# Joomla, cannot display slider and datepicker on the same page! Conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, joomla, datepicker

I have a slider on my main page and developed a simple datepicker app that also should be displayed on the homepage. I used Jumi to make a module that has the complete datepicker module including a piece of Javascript and a call for the Joomla Jquery library. However when I try to display both the slider and the datepicker on the same page, the slider disappears. I'm confident that this is a Jquery issue. When I remove the Jquery call from my module the slider appears but the datepicker functionality stops working.

I tried pretty much everything including the NoConflict mode, that does not resolve anything however. What is the best way to call for the Jquery library in this Jumi module? I basically need to call for this library only once and have both functionalities use it but the way to do this is beyond me.

The code in the module:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/css/ui-    lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js">    </script>
<script src="/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.js"></script>
<script src="/js/staying_length_cal.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('input.datepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
yearRange: "-0:+2",
changeMonth: true,
 buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
changeYear: true,
showOn: 'both',
buttonImageOnly: false
},
$.datepicker.regional['nl']);
 });
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $nights = $_POST['nights'];
$persons = $_POST['persons'];
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
$end_date = $_POST['end_date'];

header ("Location: Link that uses form information");} 
?>

 <form method="post" id="stayingCalculation">
  <fieldset>
   <h4>Ik zoek</h4>
   <select id="stayLength" name="nights" onchange="calculateTotal(); " />
    <option value="week">Week</option>
    <option value="midweek">Midweek</option>
    <option value="weekend">Weekend</option>
    <option value="twoweek">Twee weken</option>
    <option value="threeweek">Drie weken</option>
    <option value="3">3 Nachten</option>
    <option value="4">4 Nachten</option>
    <option value="5">5 Nachten</option>
    <option value="6">6 Nachten</option>
    <option value="7">7 Nachten</option>
    <option value="8">8 Nachten</option>
    <option value="9">9 Nachten</option>
    <option value="10">10 Nachten</option>
    <option value="11">11 Nachten</option>
    <option value="12">12 Nachten</option>
    <option value="13">13 Nachten</option>
    <option value="14">14 Nachten</option>
    <option value="15">15 Nachten</option>
    <option value="16">16 Nachten</option>
    <option value="17">17 Nachten</option>
    <option value="18">18 Nachten</option>
    <option value="19">19 Nachten</option>
    <option value="20">20 Nachten</option>
</select>

<h4>met</h4>
   <select name="persons">
        <option value="0">Niet relevant</option>
    <option value="1">1 persoon</option>
    <option value="2">2 personen</option>
    <option value="3">3 personen</option>
    <option value="4">4 personen</option>
    <option value="5">5 personen</option>
    <option value="6">6 personen</option>
   </select>
    <br/>

<h4>tussen</h4>
<p>   <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date"  value="" class="datepicker" data-jquerydateformat="dd-mm-yy" data-isodateformat="dd-mm-yyyy" onchange="setExpDate(this.value)" />
    </p>
  <h4>en</h4>
<p>    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_Date" value="" class="datepicker" data-jquerydateformat="dd-mm-yy" data-isodateformate="dd-mm-yyyy" onchange="setStartDate(this.value)" /> </p>
    </fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Zoeken" class="btn btn-primary"><br>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you loads jQuery in you Jumi file than it will rise an error because the jQuery may be already loaded by your site's template.

Comment: Exactly, question is what would be the best way to make sure that the Jumi module uses the Joomla JQuery library?

Comment: Have you asked the Jumi people?

Comment: Provide us code that you insert into Jumi module.

Comment: Code is provided. Have asked Jumi but no reply...

Answer (score 0):

For multiple jQuery inclusions you can use the jQueryEasy plugin which tries to include only one time jQuery.

Download the plugin
Install plugin
Enable plugin
In the plugin's configuration page, enable jQuery.

That's all.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327

Comment: I tried using the jQuery Easy plugin but it doesn't affect anything. Both modules can't work together in this way. People from Jumi haven't answered my question yet and my best guess is that de module is simply too complicated to have it coded like this.

Comment: So it could be an other thing.
You can open the developper console (F12 on chrome) and check if there is some javascript errors and let us know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it using:

```
<script>

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(function() {

jQuery( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();

jQuery( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();

});

</script>
```

instead of `$(...`

Perhaps this might help you, too!